# Errors during save in grails

Tags: grails

I have created a class;  below is the class

```
Class distanceChart{
   Vehicle v1;
   Vehicle v2;

 static contstraints = {
    v1(nullable:true)
    v2(nullable:true)
 }
}
```

When I run the application, table distance_chart got created with v1_id(null:no) ,v2_id (null:no)
and when I try save without entering the vehicles, I get an error message:

> "Please enter vehicle1" "Please enter vehicle2"

I am not getting the problem.  Even though i have specified the constraints null why it is not accepting the null values.  Can anyone help me out to solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You mis-spelled "constraints" as "contstraints" in your class definition.  This won't generate a compile or run-time error, but will fail to create the nullable constraint as you specified.